# How do I know if a project is MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

My friend has given me a visual studio project , with lots of files. 
I know for sure that it is C++ application. 
But I want to verify that if it is an MFC application or not.

The issue is since this project has been developed on a higher version (VS 2013) than mine (VS 2010), it is not opening in VS 2010.

So I thought I will make a new project and then gradually add these files.

But When I try to make a new project , I have many options to choose , such as MFC, win32 etc. 
 I guess it is an MFC application. But to be sure I want to verify that this project is indeed an MFC application. How do I do this ? Especially by just looking at the project files!

Comment: ask to your friend so. There is 3 type of MFC project too (SDI, MDI, dialog based0.

Answer (score 3):

Look into your source files and check if afx.h or afxwin.h is included any where.

Project Settings are secondary. Only if such a Header file is used in the Project the MFC libraries are included in the link phase.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off checking the source files, not the project file. For sure, the MFC library need to be present in the project file, but that option could have been left on accidentally.

You could search the source files for `CWinApp`, which is the class MFC applications need to be derived from. Also, you could try [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcw45t5d.aspx) on MSDN, which will give you some idea about source and header files typically found in an MFC project.

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 and VS2013 uses XML for **.sln/.vcxproj** files. Just create a minimal solution in VS2010. Then use a good text editor or even a file comparer to adjust settings inside the .vcxproj.

Great syntax changes occurred between VS2008 and VS2010. But since then most XML tags were kept unchanged between VS2010 and VS2013.